# What is the order and degree of this differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=x\sqrt{\frac{dy}{dx}}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What is the degree and order of the differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=x\sqrt{\frac{dy}{dx}}?$$

On squaring we get $$\left [ \frac{dy}{dx} \right ]^2=x^2\frac{dy}{dx}$$
At this stage order is 1 and degree is 2. But if I cancel the common factor it becomes $$\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2$$
Here the order is 1 and degree is 1
.
So which one is its order and degree?

Comment: Order and degree can change when you modify the original DE. For the original equation, the order is one and the degree is one.

Comment: I would say, because of the square-root, the "degree" is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cancel, you are eliminating one solution of the equation, which is dy/dx = 0. So it becomes a different equation.